# Show Json object properties

Tags: json, angular

In my application I have json array and I can display those data. all data have radio button. what I want is when I click on radio button, data of that json array item will print in html format in another component. Something like below.
[This is how it is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB8RS.jpg)

withing my product.component.ts I have below.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.wordpressService.apiCall().subscribe((data)=>{
     console.warn("get api data ",data);
     this.title=data;
   })
}
radioHandle(event : any){
     this.post=event.target.value;
  }
```

Then within my product.component.html I display some json data as below.

```
<div class='container'>
  <div id="leftDiv">
   <div *ngFor="let data of title">
    <p>
      <input type="radio"
      name="posts"
      value="{{data | json}}"
      (change)="radioHandle($event)">
      {{data.id}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="rightDiv">
  <app-productDisplay [parentData]=post></app-productDisplay>
</div>
</div>
```

now I want to pass that selected data to another component call productDisplay.component.ts

```
 @Input() public parentData: any;
```

And display the data within productDisplay.component.html

```
{{parentData}}
```

It works. But the problem is it is display json object. But I want to print some properties of json object instead of whole json

Comment: Maybe `{{parentData | json}}` will help

Comment: @EMilen It shows json data. I want to print properties separately. Something like parentData.Id. but it is not works

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the JSON first in product.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.wordpressService.apiCall().subscribe((data)=>{
     console.warn("get api data ",data);
     this.parentDataParsed = JSON.parse(data)
   })
}
```

Pass the data to the productDisplay component by data binding

```
<app-product-display [parentData]="parentDataParsed"></app-product-display>
```

In the productDisplay component, you can show individual fields

```
<p>ID: {{parentData?.id}}</p>
<p>TITLE: {{parentData?.title}}</p>
....
```